# ReactiveMongo $in operator returns zero elements

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

Having issues using the `$in` operator in a ReactiveMongo `0.11` query. For some reason the query returns zero documents, although I can confirm that the IDs exist. So I assume I'm not structuring this properly.

Here's my query:

```
val query = BSONDocument("userId" -> userId, "convoId" -> BSONDocument("$in" -> BSONArray(convoIds)))
collection.find(query).cursor[ChatDesc](ReadPreference.primaryPreferred).collect[List]()
```

I construct my `BSONArray` by applying a list:

```
BSONArray(List(id1, id2, ...))
```

Here are the IDs being used in the query:

```
List(5594ee9f02fb36b06e2925b155ea043bfb006c5a6a8436be, 552c784430a54cf55e07190955ea043bfb006c5a6a8436be, 55af435c9524018461f750ec55ea043bfb006c5a6a8436be...)
```

If I leave out the `$in` operator and manually check every `convoIds` field, I can confirm that the 3rd ID above `55af435c9524018461f750ec55ea043bfb006c5a6a8436be` is in fact present many times in the collection. Additionally, the other objects meet the criteria for the `userId` field.

My only other guess is I need to create some sort of MongoDB secondary index on the fields?

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

### Update

I've narrowed the problem to how I'm applying the `BSONArray`. If I manually paste one of the IDs like this, `BSONArray("thestringID")`, and run the query it is successful. Seems peculiar since I thought `List` was a descendant of `Traversable`?

Comment: Please indicate the versions you are using. If you have a look a the doc, you can see the

Answer (score 2):

> Please indicate the versions you are using.

If you have a look a the documentation, you can see the `BSONArray` can be created from either `Traversable[BSONValue]` or from `Producer[BSONValue]`.

It seems you're list is a `List[String]`, which is `Traversable` but not `Traversable[BSONValue]`, which means it tries apply the former constructor with `Producer[BSONValue]*`.

Indeed, there is an instance of the type class `Producer[BSONValue]` for `List[String]`, as there is one for `List` as soon as the element type is also provided one (which is the case for `String`). Such producer creates a `BSONArray` itself.

So the call `BSONArray(List("id1","id1"))` results in `BSONArray(BSONArray("id1","id2"))`, which valid, but has no sense for the query.

Comment: I added the version to my question. This answer might be more helpful if you can reference the specific API doc for `Producer` or give an example. I am, of course, appreciative if there's a cleaner and better way to fix the problem.

Comment: As for other types, the doc is in the online [Scaladoc](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/api/index.html#reactivemongo.bson.BSONArray).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use BSONArray for List, it's enough to place List in BSONDocument without anything:

```
val query = BSONDocument("userId" -> userId, "convoId" -> BSONDocument("$in" -> convoIds))
```

or in Play JSON library:

```
val query = Json.obj("convoId" -> Json.obj("$in" -> convoIds))
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to iterate through the list since the `BSONArray` doesn't seem to support scala's native `List`.

```
var idFilter = BSONArray()
matchIds.foreach( id => idFilter = idFilter ++ id)
val query = BSONDocument("userId" -> userId, "convoId" -> BSONDocument("$in" -> idFilter))
```